# AmCharts 4 : can't use categoryX for LineSeries

Tags: jquery, amcharts, amcharts4

I tried to set the dataFields of x, I tried to use categoryX but I get `Error: Data fields for series "id-126" are not properly defined` , then I try to use `series.dataFields.valueX` but it return me an number. How can I set the x to the value of `XName` so it can show `A,B,C`

```
    chart.data = [{
        "XName": "A",
        "YValue": 0.5,
    }, {
        "XName": "B",
        "YValue": 1.3,
    }, {
        "XName": "C",
        "YValue": 2.3,
    }];

    var valueXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueXAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

    var valueYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueYAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
    valueYAxis.title.text = "Amount";

    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
    series.dataFields.categoryX = "XName";
    series.dataFields.valueY = "YValue";
    series.tooltipText = "[bold]{valueY}[/]";
    series.fillOpacity = 0.3;
    series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
    series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#4c676b");
```

Answer (score 1):

`categoryX`/`categoryY` are used with a category axis for the X and Y axis respectively. Your chart is using value axes for both X and Y axes, so `categoryX` won't do anything as it is expecting a `valueX` definition in your series. You need to replace your x axis with a category axis:

```
    var categoryXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
    categoryXAxis.dataFields.category = "XName";
    categoryXAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;

    // ... 
    series.dataFields.categoryX = "XName"; // this will now work
```